# MySQL AND OR statement order

Tags: mysql

I have the below SQL Statement, but I just ran across a problem, I haven't figured out how to order the WHERE statement properly.

When I run this statement, it should return 0 because there are no questions with the categoryid of 2, and it works as long as I take out the or useranswers.level = 5 because there are other category id's that are level 5.

So my question in where do I need to put that or statement?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM useranswers INNER JOIN users on useranswers.userid = users.id 
INNER JOIN kumiquestions on useranswers.questionid = kumiquestions.id 
WHERE login = 'chris3spice' 
and kumiquestions.categoryid = 2 and useranswers.level = 4 or useranswers.level = 5;
```

Comment: change it to useransers.level IN (4, 5)  or use parenthesis to force logical grouping

Comment: You haven't stated what logic you want to implement... I guess that you want parenthesis after the categoryid = 2, but when asking a question please actually state what you're trying to achieve. Can you [edit] your question to include what you're attempting to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two solutions:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM useranswers INNER JOIN users on useranswers.userid = users.id 
INNER JOIN kumiquestions on useranswers.questionid = kumiquestions.id 
WHERE login = 'chris3spice' 
and kumiquestions.categoryid = 2 and (useranswers.level = 4 or useranswers.level = 5);
```

OR

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM useranswers INNER JOIN users on useranswers.userid = users.id 
INNER JOIN kumiquestions on useranswers.questionid = kumiquestions.id 
WHERE login = 'chris3spice' 
and kumiquestions.categoryid = 2 and useranswers.level IN (4, 5);
```

Both amount to the same thing logically.

Answer (score 0):

Use parenthesis to group your related conditions.

Answer (score 0):

The logic operators have precedence - "and" the highest, then "or".
So, you need to put paretheses, like this

```
and kumiquestions.categoryid = 2 and (useranswers.level = 4 or useranswers.level = 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM useranswers INNER JOIN users on useranswers.userid = users.id 
INNER JOIN kumiquestions on useranswers.questionid = kumiquestions.id 
WHERE login = 'chris3spice' 
and kumiquestions.categoryid = 2 and (useranswers.level = 4 or useranswers.level = 5);
```

If you do not explicitly use parentheses, the grouping is done automatically based on the location of OR, as below:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM useranswers INNER JOIN users on useranswers.userid = users.id 
INNER JOIN kumiquestions on useranswers.questionid = kumiquestions.id 
WHERE (login = 'chris3spice' 
and kumiquestions.categoryid = 2 and useranswers.level = 4) or (useranswers.level = 5);
```

That is why you did not get count(*) = 0 when you did not use parentheses.